to remove Arcgis PRO Add-in Tab By Arcgis PRO SDK .net
This the way I've removed the unwanted tab in  ConfigurationManager1.cs:
protected override void OnUpdateDatabase(XDocument database)
{
    base.OnUpdateDatabase(database);

    // Get the namespace of the root element
    var nsp = database.Root.Name.Namespace;
    
    // Retrieve all tab elements from the database
    var tabElements = database.Root.Descendants(nsp + "tab").ToList();
    
    // Create a list to store elements to be removed
    var elementsToRemove = new List<XElement>();
    
    // Iterate through each tab element
    foreach (var tabElement in tabElements)
    {
        // Get the id attribute value of the current tab element
        var id = tabElement.Attribute("id")?.Value;
    
        // Check if the tab is the "Add-In" tab or not the custom tab
        if (id == "esri_core_AddInsTab" || id != "Project_Learning_Tab1")
        {
            // Add the tab element to the list of elements to be removed
            elementsToRemove.Add(tabElement);
        }
    }    
    // Remove each element from the database
    foreach (var element in elementsToRemove)
    {
        element.Remove();
    }
}

I have tried to avoid removing the default tabs of arcgis pro and only show my custom tool tab. I've succeeded in avoiding all the other tabs except the add-in tab.
